# How to read file as ansi encoding in tcl?

Tags: file, encoding, tcl

I am not able to read the file as ansi encoding.

```
fconfigure $fd -encoding CP1250
```

I want convert the utf-8 file in ansi to pass channel to xml parser (tdom).
Can you help me?
**EDIT:** I wanted to parse xml file through tdom which is in utf-8 file encoding.
Then when I just directly (without fconfigure or encoding tcl commands) open and read that file and pass to tdom, tdom give error of full return of file data. CP1250 I am using because I want to read that file as ANSI (because ansi encoding does not give any error in tdom).

Thanking you.

Comment: Hi OliveOne, can you explain your problem in more detail please?

Comment: error is unexpectedtext {unexpected text "ÄÂ»Å¼" in document prolog around line 0}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define "I am not able to read the file as ansi encoding" — do you get any error when calling `fconfigure` as in your code snippet? or what?

Do you have the necessary encoding available? Supposedly yes, but verify by running `encoding names` in your interpreter.

The other issue which might occur (I'm not sure) is that when you do `fconfigure $fd -encoding CP1250` Tcl interprets the data read from `$fd` as being encoded in the "CP1250" Windows code page and converts it to the *Tcl's internal encoding,* which is not guaranteed to be UTF-8.  Hence if `tdom` really expects an UTF-8-encoded stream of bytes, you have to convert what you read from your file to UTF-8 explicitly.  You can do this:

```
set fd [open $filename]
fconfigure $fd -encoding cp1250
set data [encoding convertto utf-8 [read $fd]]
tdom whatever $data
```

Another approach you could try is to read file as a binary (without any interpretation of its contents and then re-encode it in whatever way you wish):

```
set fd [open $filename]
fconfigure $fd -translation binary
set data [encoding convertto utf-8 [encoding convertfrom cp1250 [read $fd]]]
tdom whatever $data
```

P.S.
Next time please *explain* what the real problem is.  For some bizzare reason people tend to think that the actual error message is not relevant while it's the most crucial bit of information in fact.

Comment: You can also use `open $filename "rb"` to open a file in binary mode. It's _exactly_ like you did `fconfigure $fd -translation binary` on it afterwards.